# Ошибка на ран проекта Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, vue-cli

I have installed node.js and vue-cli
I have tried run my project more ad more but i get this error.
how I can fix this problem

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
Require stack:

C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:955:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:803:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at idToPlugin (C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:172:14)
at C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:211:20
at Array.map ()
at Service.resolvePlugins (C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:198:10)
at new Service (C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:35:25)
at Object. (C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@VUE\cli-service\lib\Service.js',
'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@VUE\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
]
}
```

Comment: deleting package-lock.json and npm install again worked for me.

Comment: it is no true way. I hava deleted node.js and vue-cli and i chack other developers' node and vue versions.
After thats I have installed same versions.
Thats all.
Its works without problem )